# Como reutilizar a pagina de cadastro para editar no angular em um sistema CRUD?

Tags: angular

Estou criando um sistema crud, gostaria de usar a mesma página de cadastro para o editar, consigo trazer os valores, mas tem um delay de 2 segundos, primeiro ele me traz a de cadastro e depois muda pro de editar. Alguém sabe como eu posso fazer para ele não ter esse delay ? E já carregar a página com o valores para editar ? Esse é o código que estou usando, para chamar a função de editar.

```
  editar(id) {
    this.router.navigate(["edit", id], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }

  

    ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .pipe(
        map((params: any) => params["id"]),
        switchMap((id) => this.productService.getProduct(id))
      )
      .subscribe((product) => this.updateForm(product));
    }

    updateForm(product) {
       this.pageTitle = "Editar produto";
       this.form.patchValue({
         id: product.id,
         descricaoProduto: product.descricaoProduto,
         quantidade: product.quantidade,
         volume: product.volume,
         descricaoSintetica: product.descricaoSintetica,
       });
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

Como é preciso esperar a busca dos dados do produto para o preenchimento. a solução será criar um loading na tela que mostrará o formulário, somente depois de buscar as informações.

*product.component.ts*

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.loading= true;

  this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    map((params: any) => params["id"]),
    filter((value) => {
      if( value != 'add'){
        return value
      } else {
        setTimeout(()=> {
          // Aqui ficara o codigo que desativa o loading
          this.loading = false;
        }, 350)
      }
    }),
    switchMap((id) => this.productService.getProduct(id))
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (product) => {
      console.log(product)
      this.updateForm(product)
    },
    error: (error) => {
      console.error(error)
      setTimeout(()=> {
        // Aqui ficara o codigo que desativa o loading
        this.loading = false;
      }, 350)
    }
  }
  )
}

updateForm(product: any) {
  this.pageTitle = "Editar produto";
  this.form.patchValue({
    id: product.id,
    descricaoProduto: product.body,
    quantidade: product.userId,
    volume: product.userId,
    descricaoSintetica: product.title,
  });
  setTimeout(()=> {
    // Aqui ficara o codigo que desativa o loading
    this.loading = false;
  }, 350)
}
```

*product.component.html*

```
<p>product works!</p>
<p *ngIf="loading"> Carregando ... </p>
<p *ngIf="!loading"> Carregado </p>
```

O exemplo de loading que coloquei é bem simples. indico o [NgxSkeletonLoader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-skeleton-loader) que é muito bom.

obs: o setTimeOut() não é necessário. mas da um efeito bacana e evita que o loading seja rápido demais .

Comment: Valeu amigo, você é um amigo , deu certo, obrigada <3 ^^

Comment: Provavelmente não é a melhor maneira de resolver esse problema. e também é a primeira vez que usei o operador filter do rxjs. então não marque como solução. vai que aparece alguém com uma ideia melhor.